# How can I automate the creation of docker containers with node?

Tags: node.js, containers, docker-machine

I'm trying to set up a private host based on containers, but I haven't found any way to automate their creation.

Comment: You could use the [Docker Engine API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/). There are two unofficial libraries listed for NodeJS called [dockerode](https://github.com/apocas/dockerode) and [harbor-master](https://github.com/arhea/harbor-master).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.